# Non-recursive DNS server still finds google

Tags: networking, dns

For a project I set up a DNS server for a LAN environment that only contains a domain name to IP record for one website address. I would like to redirect all requests for other domains to this IP as well. I am using Simple DNS Plus and have disabled recursion. In the settings I also put the IP that I want to redirect to as a response for lame requests and requests for non-existant domains.

For the most part this works exactly as I intended, the only exception I've found is that google still works. I can still google anything, but when I then click a result I do get redirected to my predefined IP.

Why are requests to google still being processed?

Comment: Did your serveur receive the request ? Browser have a DNS cache. try a ctrl+ shift + r .

Comment: For Windows try `ipconfig /flushdns`.  You can also use NSLookup to  try to find out where it's getting the IP from.

Comment: @chaput Didn't know browsers had DNS chache as well. My dusty copy of Internet Explorer redirected everything just fine so it was indeed the browser cache. Thanks!